# how to set white translucent color to status bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-statusbar

when I set

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

status bar became black translucent, but I need white

[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGiFv.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

That's what you need. Just add this line of code to your main java file:

```
getWindow().setFlags(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS
);
```

Comment: No, I need white translucent color status bar. And I have bottom navigation. So it is not solution for my problem